# Can't retrieve an id previously passed in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code actually:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.when(getDatas(this.id)).done(function(r_getDatas){
        var json = $.parseJSON(r_getDatas);
        alert(this.id);
    });

    function getDatas(id) {
        return $.post("update.php", {
            updateType: id,
            data: $('#'+id).serializeArray()
        }, "json");
    }           
});
```

How can I run this line is the code:

```
alert(this.id);
```

Actually, the alert says:

```
undefined
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is your id declared? Somethng like `var id = 1;`

Comment: `id` isn't defined anywhere in your posted code, so what do you expect?  Maybe you want `this.id` instead: `$.when(getDatas(this.id))`

Comment: well, it is, but only as a parameter to `getDatas`

Comment: @Alnitak Ya but undefined

Comment: Code edited. I have now an undefined...

Comment: Inside `done()` callback, `this` refers to the jqXHR object, the POST request, not the FORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are you sure that `this.id` has an right value** (different then `undefined`) **in line `$.when(getDatas(this.id))`?**

---

**If so**, try something like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var myID = this.id;
$.when(getDatas(myID)).done(function(r_getDatas){
    var json = $.parseJSON(r_getDatas);
    alert(myID);
});
```

That way you capture and store the value of `this.id` into variable. When you use `alert(this.id)` your **`this` may have a different scope** (meaning) then previously and the variable will keep the right value.

---

On Firefox you can examine the value of variable in any given place of code with: `console.log(variable)`, e.g.:

```
console.log("My ID = " + myID);
```

I suggest you to check the value of `this.id` before calling `$when(getDatas(...))` and inside the function `getDatas(...){...}`.

Comment: `this.attr('id')` is just a more boring way to write `this.id` ;) The attribute ID is always parsed as property of DOM node

Comment: @A.Wolff that's right, it's kind of alias ;) I've removed the mistake.